# Download file with Resume capability for windows servers

Tags: winforms, auto-update, resume-download

I am building an Auto Updater for a winforms desktop application.

When the update is downloading, how can I provide a **Resume download** capability in case the customers internet connection breaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing a windows-only application, and you are targeting windows XP and later OSes, you can use BITS: the Background Intelligent Transfert Service.

- [MSDN page on BITS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968799%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
- [Interfacing BITS with .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188766.aspx)

It is the same service used by WindowsUpdate.

Otherwise rolling out your solution in C# using the HTTP auto-resume capabilities should not be too difficult, (using the Accept-Range directive in the HTTP request)

- [How To: Fetching Web Pages with HTTP](http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/HttpWebFetch.aspx)
- [downloading a large file](http://bytes.com/forum/thread446201.html)